# Search: display all found matches inside post

Tags: search, query-posts, excerpt

I'm working on a custom search where I'm filtering results using custom taxonomies and categories.

The search works but on the results I want to display every match inside the post, for example if I search for 'juice' I want to display many excerpts of the post where the word 'juice' was found.

I don't want to display the entire post because these are very long posts, I just need the phrases where the word was found.

Can that be done using the WordPress search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following plugin that shows the results on many phrases of the same post:

https://scott.yang.id.au/pages/search-excerpt.html